# maven 2 problems

Tags: maven

I'm getting the following error when I try to run mvn clean install -P embedded
I ve never worked with Maven before and actually hardly understand what its trying to tell me. Can someone help me to fix it?

```
    [FATAL ERROR] org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo#execute() caused a linkage error (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError) and may be out-of-date. Check the realms:
[FATAL ERROR] Plugin realm = app0.child-container[org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.2]
urls[0] = file:/Users/andrejcek/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.2/maven-clean-plugin-2.2.jar
urls[1] = file:/Users/andrejcek/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/Users/andrejcek/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.2/file-management-1.2.jar
urls[3] = file:/Users/andrejcek/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.1/maven-shared-io-1.1.jar
[FATAL ERROR] Container realm = plexus.core
urls[0] = file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-2.2.0-uber.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] org/apache/maven/shared/io/logging/MessageSink
org.apache.maven.shared.io.logging.MessageSink
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/shared/io/logging/MessageSink
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo.execute(CleanMojo.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:678)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:540)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:519)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:371)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:332)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.shared.io.logging.MessageSink
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClass(RealmClassLoader.java:214)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:250)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:398)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 1):

i have faced the same problem, but later i found very simple solution.

step1 - Download desire maven folder from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi (i have downloaded Maven 2.2.1 (Binary tar.gz))

step2 - extract the tar and put the folder to your desire location(ie. /usr/lib/)

step3 - update the path of maven where you have used it( in my case it is .bashrc)

Basically problem is your maven is corrupted and you need to follow above steps to resolve it. :)

Comment: there are two question which has same solution so i have posted it like this

Answer (score 0):

You have a corrupted Maven installation. Uninstall it, redownload maven, confirm that md5 checksums match, install it and retry.

([Similar problem thread](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Maven-Install-on-Mac-OS-X-td82913.html))

Edit: another alternative is that you have downloaded something from a repo that is broken. If reinstallation of maven does not fix the issue, check if you have a problematic repository in use (preferrably also report your configured pom dependencies here). There has been [cases like that](http://markmail.org/thread/mkuojf4axc75y2dq#query%3a+page:1+mid%3ang6essmfnspfvadp+state%3aresults), too.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have correctly setted your M2_HOME variable, as it's explained in the [installation instructions](http://maven.apache.org/download.html).